# Probability that $x$ will take a value in the future given that I know its current value

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem, time-series

I have a continuous time series signal $x$ (financial data varying with time) where the values of $x$ are exponentially distributed. The random variable $x$ changes with time, however, we assume that the probability distribution p(x) is time invariant. I am observing $x$ in real time and let's say that right now, at time $t$, it has taken a value $x \geq X_t$. I am now interested in calculating the probability that x will take a value $x \leq X_{t+T}$ at an arbitrary future point in time, $t+T$, given that we know its current value. So, mathematically I think I am interested in calculating this probability:

$$p(x \leq X_{t+T}~|~\geq X_t)$$

I have attached a drawing of this scenario below for ease of illustration. Essentially what I am asking is, given that I have observed that $x$ is currently in region #1, what is the probability that $x$ will end up in region #2 at some point in the future? Additionally, is there any possible method I can estimate the time $T$ it will take to reach region #2?

[p(x) illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN6fD.png)

I thought of using Bayes theorem to evaluate the probability above, however, from my knowledge Bayes theorem looks something like this:

$$ p(A~|~B) = \frac{p(A~\cap~B)}{p(~B~)} $$

In my case I don't understand how I can evaluate $p(A~\cap~B)$ because the two regions I am interested in do not intersect.

Comment: Question is too broad.  Some process (Markov)  have dependency.  Others don't.  There is no general answer.

Comment: Why does the two regions not intersect? It seems to me that they do intersect.

Comment: Region #1 is $x \leq X_{t+T}$ and region #2 is $x \geq X_t$ and $X_{t+T} \leq X_t$. So the two regions are separated by $X_t -X_{t+T}$ right?

Comment: That's not Bayes's theorem, it's just the definition of conditional probability. Bayes' theorem is P(A|B) = P(B|A) P(A)/P(B).

Comment: I think your main confusion about the overlap thing is that you are referring to one random variable taking multiple values. You should instead refer to that variable taking a value, then some other variable with the same distribution taking a different value later. Your notation seems a bit weird though, so are you sure you're not misunderstanding the setting you're working in? Usually $X_t$ would be a random variable and $x$ would be a constant.

Comment: The premise of the question seems to be that you have some time-sequence of random data (usually modeled as a sequence of random variables) such that the random values at two times are not independent. But we can't determine how one random value depends on another just by knowing the individual distributions of the random values. You need more detail in your model. You want to know how much time we can expect to pass to get from region 1 to region 2? Then you need at least to provide some hint about how quickly the value can change.

Comment: I agree that the question is too broad. You may want to read up on Brownian Motion and Black-Scholes model and then reformulate the question